# Getting exception when running Okta Spring Security & Okta-Hosted Login Page example

Tags: github, spring-security, sample, okta

I followed the steps in this sample code: https://github.com/okta/samples-java-spring/tree/master/okta-hosted-login
When I run the example using the command:
`mvn -Dokta.oauth2.issuer=https://{yourOktaDomain}/oauth2/default \ -Dokta.oauth2.clientId={clientId} \ -Dokta.oauth2.clientSecret={clientSecret}`

I get the following exception:
`2023-02-06 11:08:41.717  INFO 17288 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-02-06 11:08:41.725  INFO 17288 --- [           main] c.o.s.e.CodeFlowExampleApplication       : Started CodeFlowExampleApplication in 2.881 seconds (JVM running for 5.358)
2023-02-06 11:08:53.299  INFO 17288 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-02-06 11:08:53.299  INFO 17288 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-02-06 11:08:53.301  INFO 17288 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
2023-02-06 11:08:53.558 ERROR 17288 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext.getExchange()Lorg/thymeleaf/web/IWebExchange;] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext.getExchange()Lorg/thymeleaf/web/IWebExchange;
at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.util.Spring5VersionSpecificUtility.isWebMvcContext(Spring5VersionSpecificUtility.java:80) ~[thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.util.SpringVersionSpecificUtils.isWebMvcContext(SpringVersionSpecificUtils.java:118) ~[thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.util.SpringSecurityContextUtils.getAuthenticationObject(SpringSecurityContextUtils.java:127) ~[thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.auth.AuthUtils.getAuthenticationObject(AuthUtils.java:102) ~[thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.dialect.expression.SpringSecurityExpressionObjectFactory.buildObject(SpringSecurityExpressionObjectFactory.java:91) ~[thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
...`

I also tried running this sample from my Intellij IDEA IDE and when I open it I get the following error:
`'parent.relativePath' of POM com.example.okta:okta-spring-boot-oauth-code-flow-example:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\fteran\repos\demos\okta-github\samples-java-spring\okta-hosted-login\pom.xml) points at com.okta.examples:aggregator instead of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent, please verify your project structure`

I was kind of expecting the sample code to work if I was very careful to follow the instructions, which I think I did, at this point I am not sure if this is an issue on my local or if there is an issue with the sample code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue I was having. Originally, I received an error when I tried to clone the repo with the command:

```
git clone https://github.com/okta/samples-java-spring.git
```

So instead I downloaded the code via Zip file. Somehow the Zip file had the incorrect version for the dependency `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5` (`3.1.1.RELEASE`). When I was eventually able to download the repo using the git clone command, the above dependency was satisfied with version `3.0.4.RELEASE`. This other version does not throw the `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example: https://github.com/okta-samples/okta-spring-boot-sample/

It's more up-to-date.